# Counterexample to Convergent Sequence Proposition

Tags: real-analysis

The proposition is:

> If $\lim S_n = L$ and for every $n$, $S_n$ is in the interval $[a,b]$, then $L$ is also in $[a,b]$.

I have proved this effectively, but now the question is to provide a counterexample to the stronger assumption, for the interval $(a,b)$.

Basically, where this proposition does not guarantee that $L$ is also in $(a,b)$.

Comment: By the way, welcome to MSE.   I see that you haven't accepted any of the answers you got on   this site. Please do so, since otherwise - the questions remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Think about the sequence ${1\over n}$. Can you figure out the interval for the counter example?

Comment: That is the one I have kept using, but (0,1) works doesn't it?

Comment: OHHHH, because it is no longer an equality, it no longer works!  Is that right?

Comment: @DavidHouse what about (0,10)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work anymore. Take $1/n$ from $n=2$, for example. Or as @Learner suggested, just use $(0,10)$ and then you can start from $n=1$...

Comment: if the interval is (0,2) wouldn't that be fine as well.  n∈N so as long as the interval doesn't include 1 I should be ok, right?

Comment: @DavidHouse yeah thats fine!

Comment: Yep, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

What about $1/(n+1)$ in $(0,1)$?